# Active reports textbox control

Tags: activereports

I am using Active reports 6 as Report Control in my .Net application.
How will I get the value of a data bound text box control after the control is initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value after the data binding of each row which happens immediately before the section's Format event is fired.
In detail_Format event.  you can retrieve the value using the textbox value or text properties
txtMyTextbox.Text (returns the formatted text that would render in the report)
txtMyTextbox.Value (returns the bound value, without formatting)

hope this helps.

http://activereports.grapecity.com